# Correct labeling for this regular language?

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, regular-language, finite-automata, dfa

So I am a newbie computer science person and would like some help from the community in helping me understand this subject.

I have this regular language I am trying to determine is 3 things from this language: `DOUBLE = {w | w contains twice as many 0s as 1s}`

- NOT regular
- context-free
- decidable

My thinking for each is that

**it's not regular** because of the Pumping Lemma. Assume for the sake of contradiction, that DOUBLE is regular. If we were to use string `\(0^n1^n\)` then for the three conditions.

1. `|xy| ≤ n`
2. `|y| > 0`
3. For all integers i ≥ 0, the string `xy^iz` is also in L.
   When applied the Pumping Lemma doesn't not work

**is context free** because if we use a context-free grammar (CFG) that look like `S -> 0S1S | ε` generates strings that have twice as many 0s as 1s

**is decidable** because it contains twice as many 0s as 1s

Answer (score 1):

### Language is not Regular

The language is not regular which can be showed via the pumping lemma for regular languages. In your proof you should have used a string that actually is in the language e.g.: w = xyz = `0^(2p) 1^(p)`. As using a string that is already not part of the language, would provide little information about the conclusions of the pumping lemma.

Then given the pumping lemma:

- `w = xyz = 0^(2p) 1^(p)`
- `|xy| <= p`
- `|y| >= 1`
- `q = xy^(i) z`, q is in the language for all i.

As `|xy| <= p`, the substring `|xy|` exists of only zeroes.
As `|y| > 1`, there is at least one zero in y, and at most p zeroes in y.

If we pumped y, then that would mean that the output string is of the form:
`#w(0) = #y(0) * i + #x(0) + p`

The language asserts:

- `#w(0) = 2#w(1)`
- `#y(0) * i + #x(0) + p = 2p`
- `#y(0) * i + #x(0) = p`

As we can pump `i` forever, we can always reach an inequality.
Showing that there is no valid derivation among xyz, thus the pumping lemma for regular languages is not applicable, thus the language is not regular.

### Language is Context-Free

The language is a context-free language, however, not by the grammar you have specified.
The right context-free grammar for this language is:

```
S -> S0S0S1S
   | S0S1S0S
   | S1S0S0S
   | ε
```

Essentially, whenever a '1' is added we must ensure that 2 zeroes are added, the order is irrelevant, but they must be placed.
Due to this assertion, we can recursively assume that for each '1' there are 2 zeroes. Which follows the 'w contains twice as many zeroes than ones'.

### Language is Context-Sensitive, Decidable, or other language class

Showing that the language is context-sensitive, or some other complexity class is trivial.
As we already showed that it is context-free, all language classes that contains the context-free language class as a subset also accepts this language.

Examples of language classes that have the context-free language class as subset:

- Context-Sensitive
- Recursive Enumerable
- Decidable

Answer (score -2):

- NOT regular for the reason you said
- NOT context free (test your try with this [tool](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1156/tools/cfg/), you'll find that it also matches "01" which does not have twice the 0s than 1s). In general, Context-free grammars are not capable of "counting" indefinitely, you'll need a push-down automata for that
- IS decidable because you can easily code an algorithm to accept/reject a string, by counting the digits

Comment: [Non-deterministic pushdown automata recognize exactly the context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).